# How i can use mongodump & mongorestore commands with mongodriver in go-lang?

Tags: mongodb, go

How i can use mongodump &  mongorestore commands with mongodriver in go-lang? I still don't found a possible to do it..

Comment: `mongodump` and `mongorestore` are standalone programs.  How would you want to use them with `go`?

Comment: I was trying to make backuper to my app which can use from console-command.

Comment: As mentioned by @rickhg12hs, those are separate apps and are not part of the mongo-go driver. You can implement similar functionality using the driver, but it's much simpler to just run the commands.